# Математические операции с числами в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Читается файл построчно и как только попадаются числа в по шаблону, с ними производится умножение и записываются на место. Проще говоря, мне надо умножить все числа из шаблона на константу.
например, строки в файле:

```
values( " 2.326,    2.358,    2.418,    2.481,    2.601,    2.807",\
        " 2.348,    2.379,    2.439,    2.503,    2.622,    2.828");
```

Надо умножить все числа в файле на "k"

```
file = open("txt.txt","r")
for line in file:
    fix_line = re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+)', '???*k', line)
```

Пытался сделать через re.sub для замены в строке, но остановился на том, как оформить замену. Как захватить каждое число и заменить его на новое число, отличающиеся на коэффициент "k".
Может есть более простой подход по замене чисел?

Comment: У вас строки произвольные? Или же они имеют представленный Вами вид?

Comment: В данной ситуации я сильно облегчил задачу. Подробнее звучит так, что в текстовом файле с данными находить шаблон, который описал выше и все числа в этом шаблоне умножить на коэффициент "k". Количество строк с числами в шаблоне может варьироваться. То есть, файл с таблицами чисел в поле values();.

Comment: Шаблон указан в регулярке?

Comment: да, если я правильно вас понял, что числа записаны в файле через точку. Ищу сначала шаблон values();, который содержит числа, а потом числа в шаблоне, чтобы их исправить на "число*k".

Comment: @BorisN, а что обозначает обратный слеш в строке шаблона? Числа в шаблоне распологаются в одной строке? Вы можете привести несколько примеров строк из вашего файла с шаблонами точно в таком же формате как в файле (без дополнительных переводов строк и т.д.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Требуется итерироваться по всем найденным числам, поочерёдно извлекать их и заменять на модифицированное число.

При этом следует учитывать, что после модификации числа, строка ему соответствующая может отличаться по длине. А значит, нужно накапливать суммарное изменение "чисел-строк" и учитывать это при вставке строки.

```
import re

k = 1.2  # Коэффициент
file = open("txt.txt")
sum_delta = 0  # Суммарное количество изменений длин строк
for line in file:
    new_line = line
    for index in re.finditer(r'(\d+\.\d+)', line):
        interval = index.span()

        old_value_str = line[interval[0]:interval[1]]
        new_value_str = str(k * float(old_value_str))

        #  Модификация строки. Используем преффикс и суффикс от старой строки и новую "число-строку"
        new_line = new_line[:interval[0] + sum_delta] + \
                   new_value_str + \
                   new_line[interval[1] + sum_delta:]
        sum_delta += len(new_value_str) - len(old_value_str)

print(new_line)
```

Comment: спасибо за идею, сработало, за исключением того, что float-числа получались дикими, что ломало алгоритм и получался следующий вид таблицы 
              values( " 2.7912,    2.8296,    2.9016,    2.9772,    3.1212,    3.3684",\
                      " 2.348,2.8175999999999997.379,2.8548.439,2.9268.503,3.0036.622,3.1464.828"3.3935999999999997                      " 2.373,    2.405,    2.465,    2.528,2.8476000000000004.647,2.8859999999999997.854"2.95799999999999973.03363.17639999999999973.4248                      " 2.459,    2.490,    2.551,    2.614,    2.733,    2.940");

Comment: заменил 
    new_value_str = str(k * float(old_value_str))
на
    new_value_str = str(format(round(k * float(old_value_str),3),'.3f'))
и все заработало